# share entity framework interface cross projects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, tdd, solid-principles

How can I share Entity Framework MyEntitiesDbContext interface cross projects?
I would like to follow S.O.L.I.D Principles and use it for testing other projects.

Main problem is sharing model entities with interface and not having loop reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I share Entity Framework MyEntitiesDbContext interface cross
>   projects? I would like to follow S.O.L.I.D Principles and use it for
>   testing other projects.

To achieve this, you would need to make EF generated classes to implement interfaces and then use mocks (Rhino Mocks, maybe) to test your code.

> Main problem is sharing model entities with interface and not having
>   loop reference.

To avoid loop references, you will need the interfaces to be generated and contained in a separate assembly which does not refers back to the EF assembly.

These are just 2 of the many difficulties that hit people really hard when they try to use EF even though it is now version 6.0

Fortunately, you can download the T4 files from https://entityinterfacegenerator.codeplex.com/

They help answer the questions above.

Comment: hehe funny story just two days before your post I wrote almost exactly same templates, also based on entity framework t4 source. Anyway thanks for link.

Comment: Big ideas tend to collide. The good news is that we will all be able to save hours of work for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this goal by used t4 templates for generate fakes classes. You can generate

- Common interface of databaseContext
- Standart realization for main solution, that implements common interface
- Fake for testing, that implements common interface.

For understand t4 templates you can read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx. I hope that this article will help you. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did like that at the beginning, maybe without using t4 but I couldn't figured out how to deal with entity framework objects. I've got reference loop error. Entities are not shared.